# How do I parse a string for key value pairs with no delimiters?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing, string-search

How do I parse a string in C# to extract key-value pairs without any delimiters between key and value?

I have a string that looks like this

```
string str = "\nFIRSTNAMEJOHN\nLASTNAMESMITH\nADDRESS1590 GRACE STREET\nBIRTHDATE04201969"
```

After splitting on \n I get a collection of strings that looks like

```
string[] properties = ["FIRSTNAMEJOHN","LASTNAMESMITH", etc.]
```

I want to loop through the split array of these strings and extract the key-value pair from each individual string, so that I can populate the properties of an object such as...

```
Person person = new Person() 
{ FIRSTNAME = JOHN,
  LASTNAME = SMITH,
  etc...
}
```

What is the cleanest way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: What are you getting your data from that is causing the data to have no delimeter? Are you sure there is not a unprintable character in there as the delimeter?

Comment: You can do this in a fairly straightforward manner. First, I used your string input. I create a public enum called FieldNames. To get the string value, I created a class called EnumStringValue that allows you to create an attribute for each enum member. Finally, I create a ParseString method which takes a string input. It splits on the '\n' as before, but inside this method it calls on a ParseLine method that takes each of the items in the split array. I can send if needed, there isn't enough room here to paste the whole thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a class that has those properties, then get the properties of the object through reflection (so we can use a loop), split the string on the `\n` character, then for each property, and for each setting, if the setting starts with the property name, set the property value based on the rest of the setting string.

For example:

```
class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string BirthDate { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{FirstName} {LastName}, born on {BirthDate}, lives at: {Address}";
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "\nFIRSTNAMEJOHN\nLASTNAMESMITH\nADDRESS1590 GRACE STREET\nBIRTHDATE04201969";
        var user = new User();
        var properties = typeof(User).GetProperties();
        var settings = str.Split('\n');

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            foreach (var setting in settings)
            {
                if (setting.StartsWith(property.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    property.SetValue(user, setting.Substring(property.Name.Length));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(user);

        GetKeyFromUser("\n\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]